# Import CSS from an HTML-file as external CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, importerror

As the title reads, I want to **import an HTML-file as external CSS** to a website.
Just hear me out: my problem is that I'm working with a very inconvenient CMS that doesn't let me upload CSS-files no matter what.

I'm able to write CSS inside the page directly via HTML-style-tag but that generates a lot of text on every site and also makes maintaining CSS tedious.

As I can't upload CSS-files, I thought maybe I can create a **dummy-site inside the CMS with only CSS** in it and then later import that site as CSS.
*The idea was: when parsed, the HTML of the site (header, body, etc.) will just be skipped (as when CSS has i.e. type-errors) while any valid CSS found is going to be imported.*

Now when I try importing this website with

```
<style type="text/css">   @import url(dummyCSSWebsiteURL); </style>
```

(as the CMS also doesn't grant me access to the header of a page),
I - of course - get the error:

> "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html"

as I am obviously requesting an HTML-file and not CSS.

I also tried jQuery to simply include all the dummy-HTML into an element (that I would have just not displayed):

```
$("#cssDummy").load(dummyCSSWebsiteURL);
```

but I get 2 errors that are probably just showing what a horribly inefficient idea this is:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, ["..."], is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message.

maybe I am just disregarding (or not understanding) things on a conceptual level at all but I still wonder if there is a workaround for this problem?

---

**EDIT: I found a workaround**

Definitely don't recommend. Try using different server as pointed out in the comments if you can.
I used an XMLHttpRequest to get the external site's HTML, then used regEx to match the content of the div on the page that contains the css and - with added style-tags - inserted the matched css into a div on the page.

Code for external site that contains the CSS:

```
<div id="generalCode">.testBox{background-color: red; min-height: 200px;}</div>
```

Code on site that imports the external CSS:

```
<div class="testBox">
</div>  
<div id="cssCodeOnPage">
</div>

<script>
// use onload if you want
getCssCode();

function getCssCode(){
  // send request to page where div #generalCode contains css
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', dummyCSSWebsiteURL);

  xhr.onload = function(){
     // use regex to separate css from rest of html
     var re = /<div id="generalCode">([\s\S]*?)<\/div>/;
     var cssString = xhr.response.match(re)[1];
     cssString = "<style>" + cssString +"</style>";
     // insert css into div
     var cssDivOnPage = document.getElementById('cssCodeOnPage');
     cssDivOnPage.innerHTML = cssString;
} 
  xhr.send();  
}
```

(sorry for this monstrosity of a question..)

Comment: _“The idea was: when parsed, the HTML of the site (header, body, etc.) will just be skipped (as when CSS has i.e. type-errors) while any valid CSS found is going to be imported.”_ - nah, I think that is pretty ridiculous to begin with. Error correction might work satisfactory for smaller errors _inside_ the CSS, but don’t expect this to work with a whole bunch of “nonsense” HTML coming before it.

Comment: I see. Fair enough!

Comment: so you can't host a css file on a completely different server? or use a CDN url? assuming that currently `dummyCSSWebsiteURL = "www.yourCMSthatWontServeCSS.html"`

Comment: have you tried making the css style tag a partial html file and then using it that way so its all deduped?

Comment: Just found a workaround now by using regex on an XMLHttpRequest. Hope, nobody else will ever need this but check it out in the question if you're interested

Comment: @ono2012 good suggestion to just upload css on different server! Specific problem for me in this case is that anyone working on the site after me would need access to the uploaded file in case they want to change anything. So would work but not ideal in my case. 
Sorry, guess I don't have enough rep to upvote

Comment: As long as you found something to work, win! Spinning up/having access a different server can be daunting/unavailable for some people. It's not my forte, looks like it'll call for the css each page load? You won't benefit from any caching? Maybe it's just not a concern and the manageability is more important.

Comment: Indeed, caching doesn't seem to be supported for the request. As only raw html is being transferred (no images or such) for me the resulting un-cashable ~6KB are definitely neglectable in favor of accessibility. But very good point. Can see this becoming an issue when scaling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best option is to load that HTML page into an iframe, query the styles out of hte iframe, and then attach that to the current document. I created a **live example on Glitch [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/peat-vivacious-newsprint?path=script.js%3A24%3A0)**.

Nothing but the `<style>` block will be copied from the HTML. The external HTML document does need to be an actual HTML document though (`<html><head><style>....`), otherwise the page won't be queryable to retrieve the CSS.

This is an example in plain JavaScript:

```js
// Create an iframe
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

// Make it not visible
iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";

// This will run once the HTML page has loaded in the <iframe>
iframe.onload = () => {
  // Find the <style> element in the HTML document
  const style = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector("style");

  // Take that <style> element and append it to the current document's <head>
  document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);

  // Remove the <iframe> after we are done.
  iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
};

// Setting a source starts the loading process
iframe.src = "css.html";

// The <iframe> doesn't actually load until it is appended to a document
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: This looks very promising! Will test once I find time. If I understand correctly, the "css.html" is actually being loaded as a document and can therefore benefit from caching?

Comment: Yes, the "css.html" would be getting retrieved just as a page. It would be subject to whatever caching configuration is set for that page. If the cache headers for that page are set to allow caching, a user's browser should only pull down that "css.html" page once per session at most.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in a different way. However not through JS, but `PHP include`

For that however, your server needs to support PHP and need to use PHP instead of HTML as documents. Sounds more complicated now then it actually is. To use PHP the document has to becalled `.php` at the end instead of `.html` e.g. `index.php`.
The document itself can be written the very same way as you write HTML websites.

Now for the issue to use PHP include. you inlcude the CSS as head style:

index.php:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <?php 
      include('styles.css');
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    content
  </body>
</html>
```

the line `<?php include('url'); ?>` will load a file mentioned in the url server sided into the document. Therefor you only need to create another file with the name `styles.css` and write your css in there the normal way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply !
Unfortunately i can't upload php-files nor do I have access to a page's header - let alone turn it into a .php... The way the CMS actually works is: the user has a box for a the site's headline and a box for content. Upon save, the HTML is generated by the system..

Comment: well thats a shame. Then I seriosly would consider a different hoster. For your needs this hoster is surely not the right plattform for your needed tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You Do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read the question again. It was specifically said, that CSS files cant be used. Therefor your answer is useless. Also, always explain your answer that others can understand it and reproduce a solution. A person that wouldnt know about linking CSS-Files wouldnt know anything more about after your anwser.